# Remote desktop to Windows 7 always forces me to go through login screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, login

I'm trying to connect to a Windows 7 box via Remote Desktop. I have saved the correct credentials for the connection, but the Windows 7 box always forces me to login manually anyway: I have to choose my account icon from the login screen and then type my password. I've tried refreshing my credentials and RDP-ing in from other boxes, but no matter what I do, this particular box always forces me to login manually. What can I do to skip the login screen? (The funny thing is that always used to work correctly, but stopped for some reason several months ago.)

Comment: Does this also happen when you are logged out on that computer? I noticed this too on win10 if I keep the session logged on. You can also logout through rdp. Don't just disconnect butuse the logout option.

Comment: Yes, it happens even when I’m totally logged out on that computer. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Started happening to me after the April 2018 update.